# An AngularJS directive to validate a field when a non-zero sum has been entered into another

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angular-directive

I have two form fields - an employee count and a gross payroll amount.

```
<div ng-repeat="payroll in report.payrolls">
    <input type="number" min="0" class="input-mini" sister-value="{{payroll.grossPayrollAmount}}" ng-model="payroll.employeeCount" type="text">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

    <input ng-blur="payroll.grossPayrollAmount = Math.round(payroll.grossPayrollAmount)" type="number" min="0" class="input-small"  ng-model="payroll.grossPayrollAmount" type="text">
</div>
```

The user does not have to enter a non-zero value for either. HOWEVER, if they enter a non-zero value for one then they must do so for the other, and that is what I want to validate against.

These fields repeat in sets - so a pair for each payroll, so I'm not sure if getting them by an ID or class will work.

I've written a few custom validation directives before, but never one that checks for a value in another, related field.

Comment: If my answer worked for you, it would be great if you accept it with the green tick, so others can see it's valid ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to make a directive surrounding both inputs:

```
<directive>
    <input type="number" min="0" ng-model="payroll.employeeCount" type="text">

    <input ng-blur="payroll.grossPayrollAmount = Math.round(payroll.grossPayrollAmount)" type="number" min="0" class="input-small"  ng-model="payroll.grossPayrollAmount" type="text">
</directive>
```

So both values will be available from it, you can access them with element.find().

You use element.find() just like you would use jQuery. For example, setting an id="employeeCount" to the first input, you can access it with element.find('#employeeCount'), so you get the first input **element**, finally you access to its value with element.find('#employeeCount').val().

**note: if you're not used to jQuery, remember to add the dot (.) before a class name and a hash (#) before an id name.**

Here, you have a list of methods that you can use with any element, including "find()": https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

---

Update:
This will also work for multiple pairs of inputs, you just have to repeat the directive tag, for example:

```
<directive>
    <input [...] >

    <input [...] >
</directive>
<directive>
    <input [...] >

    <input [...] >
</directive>
```

The directive will work independently for each instance you create.

Comment: Wow, I didn't even think of that. Can you illuminate on how to use element.find() in this context? I'm not super familiar with directives yet, and I haven't used element.find() before.

Also, thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake with the element.find() content, if you set an id you access the element with a "#", and if you set a class, you use a "."

Comment: So, each pair of fields repeats for each payroll - i.e. a gross payroll and an employee count for Payroll 1, and for Payroll 2, and so on. Do you know if fetching them by ID will still work in that context?

Would I have to do something like get the parent and then from there get the sibling value, as I might do in jQuery?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your question (English's not my first language). If you program your directive correctly, you can reuse it so many times you want, the find() you do inside the directive will search inside the tag so it won't matter if there are more fields with this tag outside it.

Anyway, it might be a better idea to use a class instead of an id if you're going to repeat this code.

Comment: Sorry, I updated my original question. Basically the two fields are group together and the group repeats. I was just curious if your solution would still work in that case. I left that detail out of my original question by mistake.

Comment: Yes, but you should repeat the "directive" tag also, with the pair of inputs inside, and these will work independently. If the directive is well done it should work also in that case.

Comment: Awesome. Any idea as to how I would use $watch or $observe on the directive element's children's values?

Comment: Just use the $watch with its ng-model value, it was something like:
 scope.$watch("payroll.employeeCount", function(value){ ... });

Remember to validate my answer if it works ;)

Comment: Thanks a ton for the help. I'm trying to piece things together now. I'll validate soon.